# About deploying web application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed my web application in the IIS 7, I am even successfully able to browse also except for some pages it is showing the below error.

> An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start
>   monitoring changes to 'D:\DEV\Prime\Proj\Web.Prime\support\web.config'
>   because access is denied.

Have given all the permission rights, but still unable to get the output

Any solutions please.

Comment: Is there any dependency set on `web.config`? why its looking for web.config change?

Comment: This seems to be a permissions issue, are you 100% sure that the permissions on **all** of the folders and files are correct?

Comment: @Nunners Yes I have given all the permissions

Comment: @Murali Dependency in the sense??

Comment: @SumaMutalikdesai just chill :P

Comment: @SumaMutalikdesai, its like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67z4z916.aspx